# Swift 4 .plist handling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, plist

I have an .plist file, where I will store different locations which the user later can read/modify. But I can't seem to get the code working...

My .plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>MAIN TITLE</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>NAME IN TABLECELL</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>X</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I want to make the `MAIN TITLE` to  be the title of the section.
My code is:

```
func readPlist() {
        guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SavedPlaces", withExtension: "plist") else { return }
        do {
            let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
            print(plist)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

But this throws several erros, amongst:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10b39ddd8) to 'NSArray' (0x10b39e008).
```

Is there a way where I can get all the values, without the use of NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: Your plist is a `Dictionary` at top level (there is `<dict>` at the start), not an `Array`. And `[[String:Any]]` is an `Array` of `Dictionaries`, so the conversion can't work.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
```

to

```
let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Any]
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the root object of the plist file is a `<dict>`ionary – which is still easier to identify than in JSON

To get rid of collection types array and dictionary use the `Decodable` protocol and two custom structs and `PropertyListDecoder`.

```
struct SavedPlaces: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case mainTitle = "MAIN TITLE" }

    let mainTitle : [Title]
}

struct Title: Decodable {
    let name : String
}
```

---

```
func readPlist() {
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SavedPlaces", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    let plist = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(SavedPlaces.self, from: data)
    print(plist.mainTitle)
}
```

The exclamation marks are intended. As the file is located in the bundle it's immutable and the code must not crash. It it does you made a design mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The .plist file is a Dictionary and you're forcefully converting it to an Array of Dictionary `[[String:Any]]`

Replace below line from your code:

```
let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]
```

with:

```
if let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String:Any] {
            print(plist)
}
```

Using [if let](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) will be an added advantage as it will help you in checking null value for the response of PropertyListSerialization.

Hope this helps!